# Upload image via SFTP put using PHP is uploading an 0 bytes file

Tags: php, html, sftp, phpseclib

I'm trying to upload an image to a remote SFTP server using PHP and HTML form to get the file. The file is uploaded successfully but when I check the directory, the file had 0 bytes (or just 1 byte).

I already checked the php.ini "upload_max_filesize" and is all right. I've tried a lot of codes but it's still the same. Here is that part of the code:

```
    include('remote_conexion.php'); //this file already has the include SFTP.php and the connection

    $foto = ($_FILES['avatar']['name']);
// Upload file
$sftp->put('/home/user/images/avatars/',$foto, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
```

Here is a screenshot with the file uploaded to the server. Just 1 byte, I don't know what to do.
https://prnt.sc/pj9ng1

Comment: You say your screenshot shows a file that's 1 byte, but the screenshot says "1 KB". How many bytes is it supposed to be?

Comment: Oh, yes, my mistake, it's supposed to be a 172KB jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PHP [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name']
//The original name of the file on the client machine.

$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']
//The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the 
server.
```

Just change "name" to "tmp_name", but after or before that you have to [rename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) the file, because temporary filenames are ugly

Comment: I tried this and is the same problem, it's just save the file with 1 byte

Comment: @harukauni - does `echo file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);` give you the full contents of the file?

Comment: no, to get the contents you can use the file_get_contents function

Comment: Maybe this answer does not solve all your problems, but it's definitely something that you **need to do**. So adjust your code as suggested, and tell us exact results you get after. Including an answer to Kenster's comment at your question.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem! I just has to add another variable with the tmp_name and add this to my sftp->put
Here is the code:

```
$foto = ($_FILES['avatar']['name']);
$foto2 = ($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);
$sftp->put('/home/natalia/images/avatars/'.$foto, $foto2 , NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
```